# WooCommerce 3 Item Meta display only the Value

Tags: php, woocommerce

In WooCommerce 3 `wc_display_item_meta` displays this HTML

```
<ul class="wc-item-meta">
<li><strong class="wc-item-meta-label">Größe:</strong>
<p>5000 g</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Can you please help me to display only 5000 g?
This filter `woocommerce_display_item_meta` exists.

Thank you, Oliver

Comment: You have to format your question correctly with no navigation link for the people who is reading

Comment: What have you tried so far to get it how you want?

Comment: To be honest I don't know where to start. Before WooCommerce 3 the item meta was displayed like so `if ( ! empty( $item_meta->meta ) ) {
     echo '<br/><small>' . nl2br( $item_meta->display( true, true, '_', "\n" ) ) . '</small>';
    } ` and I could display only the value like so `add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_items_meta_display', function ($output, $obj) {
if($obj->product->parent->product_type == 'variable') {
    $output = ltrim(explode(':', $output)[1]);
}
return $output; },10,2); `